# Google Test: how to EXPECT_EQ non printable ASCII values

Tags: c++, testing, googletest

In my test I set an EXPECT_EQ() on a char against some characters like 'a', 'b' etc... so far so good.

Now I should test against a non printable ASCII character (0xFE). My character is defined as 'char' so a direct test against the literal 0xFE will fail every time!

```
char a;
a = 0xFE;
EXPECT_EQ(a, 0xFE);   <-- fail!!!
```

Comment: Did you try `unsigned char a;`?

Comment: What is the output? 0xfe is 254, which doesn't fit char

Comment: I need to stick to char type, not unsigned char

Comment: I need to test against the non printable ASCII value 0xFE but I cannot use the literal 0xFE as it's out of bound for a char (-128,+127)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're assigning 254 to `char a`. As you know, a `char` is wide enough to hold 
it without truncation, but it exceeds the the positive range of `char` [0,127].
It goes negative, with integral value of -2. Hence it is integrally unequal to 254 and
the `EXPECT_EQ` fails.

So, in that `EXPECT_EQ`, you must insist on comparison with the *unsigned*
integral value that is in `a`:

```
char a;
a = 0xFE;
EXPECT_EQ((unsigned char)a, 0xFE);
```